# Where in Swift is defined that we can use `[]` as Array literal?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to find in Swift documentation where it is defined, but I couldn't.

I expect something like following:

```
typealias [] = Array
typealias [Element] = Array<Element>
typealias [AnyObject] = Array<AnyObject>
```

So **why it is possible to use `[]` instead of `Array` as initializer**?

### Edit depending on answer

I try to do the same with my custom `Person` class but it doesn't work:

```
class Person: ArrayLiteralConvertible {

    typealias Element
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: Self.Element...)
}

let personNames: Person = ["John", "Mark", "Kris"]
```

Comment: [ArrayLiteralConvertible](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)?

Comment: I would imagine this to be a language (complier) feature. Check [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Parse/ParseType.cpp#L88-L90).

Answer (score 2):

It's defined in the [Summary of the Grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_array-literal), in the definition of `array-literal`:

```
array-literal → [ array-literal-items(opt) ]
array-literal-items → array-literal-item ,(opt) | array-literal-item , array-literal-items
array-literal-item → expression
```

In more "descriptive" text, this particular case is defined in *The Swift Programming Language,* [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) in the section on Arrays:

> #### Creating an Empty Array
>
> You can create an empty array of a certain type using initializer syntax:
>
> ```
> var someInts: [Int] = [] 
> print("someInts is of type [Int] with \(someInts.count) items.")
> // Prints "someInts is of type [Int] with 0 items."
> ```
>
> Note that the type of the `someInts` variable is inferred to be
> `[Int]` from the type of the initializer.

To your updated question, the correct syntax (circa Swift 5, though your question is from and older version), would be:

```
class Person: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    required public init(arrayLiteral elements: String...) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it a as a literal everything that conforms to literal protocols  . Sets as Array conforms to `ArrayLiteralConvertible` protocol, you can declare a set by using the same array literal sintax and specifing the type to avoid compiler confusion or they still will be inferred as `Array`:

```
let set: Set = ["Hello","Bye"]
```

To conforms array literal protocol you must provide an initializer:

```
protocol ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    typealias Element
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...)
}
```

There is a nice post on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)

Documentation define a literal as:

> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a type, such
>   as a number or string.

Where it a literal first defined? I guess it's the duty of the compiler detect them and substitute with the proper type.

Comment: I put my custom example in question. Could you explain me how to implement this in my custom class?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding it, why would a Person have a collection of string? You can create a PersonList object and conform it to ArrayLiteralConvertible or a Person object and make it conform to StringLiteralObject. I can't write code right now(I'm on iPad), but if you read the post of NSHipster it explains how to do

Comment: Ok, it is only for example purposes. May be PersonList also.